# Does the wave function of a particle collapse if info about an observable is available in seperate chunks for many observers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, observables, wavefunction-collapse

To start, I just started learning QM today so... keep that in mind. What I was trying to say is: suppose (for example) there is a box with a subatomic particle in it, the box is a 3D space so we plot it using (x,y,z) coordinates. So the observable here is the position of the particle which can be anywhere in the box (any coordinates x,y,z) say an observer 1 knows the X coordinate of the particle, an observer 2 knows the Y coordinate of the particle, and an observer 3 knows the Z coordinates of the particle. In this situation, does the wave function collapse?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the wavefunction "collapses" in all three dimensions. The fact that the information is recorded in three different places is irrelevant. It may as well have been recorded all in one place. The "observers" can be three different people, one person, a photograph that nobody ever sees, or just an ambient atmosphere. The important thing is that (1) the three observables $X,Y,Z$ **commute** with each other, and (2) information about all three of them has made an irreversible impact on the surroundings (observers, atmosphere, or whatever). Measurements of mutually commuting observables have compatible outcomes — they irreversibly affect the surroundings in compatible ways.

Many physicists (including me) agree that "collapse" idea should be regarded only as a convenient short-cut, not as a physical process. Explaining *why* many physicists agree about this would be an unnecessary digression here, but it's something to watch for as you continue learning QM.

Comment: I think this question raises a more subtle issue. The "collapse", in addition to being a short-cut, is an observer dependent description of events. This issue has been debated a lot with the Wigner's "friend" type of scenarios. Your answer addresses the scenario where the 3 observers are like 3 computers in the same lab. If, however, the 3 observers are isolated and non-communicating, I think each observer sees a partial collapse for the variable it measured. Only from the perspective of a 4th observer that "measures" the memory of the first 3 observers, the particle collapses completely.

Comment: @oleg Still trying to process your interesting comment... How about this: An "observer" corresponds to a set of observables, representing things that the given "observer" has the ability to measure. Two states that are different with respect to the full set of observables can become equivalent when restricted to a single "observer's" observables. In that sense, different observers may assign different states to the same situation, each designed to give the correct answers only for a different subset of observables. Is this what you mean by "partial collapse"?

Comment: In your second comment, your operational definition of "observer"  is indeed the way I tend to think about observers. But, in this case, all I meant by "partial collapse" is just the regular collapse associated with a measurement of only one of $X,Y,Z$. What I meant earlier is that, when observer $A$ measures $X$, externally, this process is described by a unitary evolution such that $A$'s measurement record (memory) gets entangled with the x degree of freedom of the particle (why subjectively we experience concrete outcomes is the big unanswered question).

Comment: Then, if we observe how the measurements by $A,B,C$ happens from the perspective of a super observer (the 4th one), all it sees is each of $A,B,C$ gets entangled with the different degrees of freedom of the particle. There may be some interesting issues here that have to do with monogamy of entanglement. In your scenario, I think $A,B$ end up agreeing on $Y$ because $A$ will get enetalged with $B$ if it tries to measure $Y$. Their outcomes for $Y$ will be strictly correlated. (I did not expect to ignite an in depth discussion on this but it is interesting to think about it).

Comment: @oleg Okay, now I see what you mean. (I deleted my 1st comment since it missed what you meant.) If we start with a state $\sum_{x,y,z}|x,y,z,A,B,C\rangle$, omitting coefficients to reduce clutter, then the result of the trio of measurements described in the OP is $\sum_{x,y,z}|x,y,z,A_x,B_y,C_z\rangle$, using notation that's hopefully clear. We could take a partial trace over $B$ and $C$ to represent $A$'s lack of knowledge of $y$ and $z$, and then we have a mixed state that is diagonal in $Y$ but that is not projected onto a single value $y$.

Comment: @oleg And if $A$ then acquires info about $y$, the state becomes $\sum_{x,y,z}|x,y,z,A_{xy},B_y,C_z\rangle$, using notation that's hopefully clear again. This outcome couldn't have been predicted by $A$ alone, but it was inevitable and could be predicted by anyone who has access to everything $A,B,C$ know. The "inevitable" part is what I implicitly emphasized in the way I wrote the answer, and your comment emphasizes the "but $A$ couldn't have predicted it" part. Both correct.

Comment: It is hard to talk about it without careful and lengthy exposition but it seems we are in agreement. I think the subject of the role of observer (both operational and relational aspects of it) does not receive enough attention. When I talk to research physicists (I'm assuming you are one), it sounds like many are very interested in a better understanding of the role of observer in quantum theory. Yet there are very few people who actually work on it.